# Carousel Navigation icon in Django

Tags: html, css, django, carousel

```
{% extends 'shop/basic.html' %}
{% block css %}
.col-md-3
{
display: inline-block;
margin-left:-4px;
}
.carousel-indicators .active {
background-color: blue;
}
.col-md-3 img{
width: 170px;
height: 200px;
}
body .carousel-indicator li{
background-color: blue;
}
body .carousel-indicators{
bottom: 0;
}
body .carousel-control-prev-icon,
body .carousel-control-next-icon{
background-color: blue;
}
.carousel-control-prev,
.carousel-control-next{
top: auto;
bottom: auto;
padding-top: 222px;
}
body .no-padding{
padding-left: 0,
padding-right: 0;
}
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
{% load static %}
<div class="container">

    <!--Slideshow starts here -->
    {% for product, range, nSlides in allProds %}
    <h5 class="my-4">Flash Sale On {{product.0.category}} - Recommended Items</h5>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="demo{{forloop.counter}}" class="col carousel slide my-3" data-ride="carousel">
            <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#demo{{forloop.counter}}" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                {% for i in range %}
                <li data-target="#demo{{forloop.parentloop.counter}}" data-slide-to="{{i}}"></li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            <div class="container carousel-inner no-padding">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    {% for i in product %}
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                        <div class="card align-items-center" style="width: 18rem;">
                            <img src='/media/{{i.image}}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title" id="namepr{{i.id}}">{{i.product_name}}</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">{{i.desc|slice:"0:53"}}...</p>
                                <span id="divpr{{i.id}}" class="divpr">
                                    <button id="pr{{i.id}}" class="btn btn-primary cart">Add To Cart</button>
                                </span>
                                <a href="/shop/products/{{i.id}}"><button id="qv{{i.id}}" class="btn btn-primary cart">QuickView</button></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 and forloop.counter > 0 and not forloop.last %}
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- left and right controls for the slide -->
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo{{forloop.counter}}" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo{{forloop.counter}}" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

     <!-- Left and Right controls for the second carousel -->
     <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#anotherDemo{{ forloop.counter }}" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#anotherDemo{{ forloop.counter }}" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>
</div>


</div>
{% endblock %}
{% block js %}
<script>
// Find out the cart items from localStorage
if (localStorage.getItem('cart') == null) {
    var cart = {};
} else {
    cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
    document.getElementById('cart').innerHTML = Object.keys(cart).length;
    updateCart(cart);
}
// If the add to cart button is clicked, add/increment the item
$('.cart').click(function() {
    var idstr = this.id.toString();
    if (cart[idstr] != undefined) {
        cart[idstr] = cart[idstr] + 1;
    } else {
        cart[idstr] = 1;
    }
    updateCart(cart);
    
});
//Add Popover to cart
$('#popcart').popover();
updatePopover(cart);
function updatePopover(cart)
{
    console.log('We are inside updatePopover');
    var popStr = "";
    popStr = popStr + "<h5> Cart for your items in my shopping cart </h5><div class='mx-2 my-2'>";
    var i = 1;
    for (var item in cart){
        popStr = popStr + "<b>" + i + "</b>. ";
        popStr = popStr + document.getElementById('name' + item).innerHTML.slice(0, 19) + "... Qty: " + cart[item] + '<br>';
        i = i+1;
    }
    popStr = popStr + "</div>" 
    console.log(popStr);
    document.getElementById('popcart').setAttribute('data-content', popStr);
    $('#popcart').popover('show');
}
function updateCart(cart) {
    for (var item in cart) {
        document.getElementById('div' + item).innerHTML = "<button id='minus" + item + "' class='btn btn-primary minus'>-</button> <span id='val" + item + "''>" + cart[item] + "</span> <button id='plus" + item + "' class='btn btn-primary plus'> + </button>";
    }
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
    document.getElementById('cart').innerHTML = Object.keys(cart).length;
    console.log(cart);
    updatePopover(cart);
}
// If plus or minus button is clicked, change the cart as well as the display value
$('.divpr').on("click", "button.minus", function() {
    a = this.id.slice(7, );
    cart['pr' + a] = cart['pr' + a] - 1;
    cart['pr' + a] = Math.max(0, cart['pr' + a]);
    document.getElementById('valpr' + a).innerHTML = cart['pr' + a];
    updateCart(cart);
});
$('.divpr').on("click", "button.plus", function() {
    a = this.id.slice(6, );
    cart['pr' + a] = cart['pr' + a] + 1;
    document.getElementById('valpr' + a).innerHTML = cart['pr' + a];
    updateCart(cart);
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

I made some carousels by their categories in my e-commerce website but I not getting the navigation button except for the first one. I used for loop to implement this. The first carousel is working nicely but after the first one, I am not getting any navigation button for those carousels. I made these carousels using bootstrap.

I can't understand what is the issue here... Is my CSS is faulty or is the whole method?